Help with IKEv2 VPN Connection Error: NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
I’m currently having trouble setting up an IKEv2 VPN connection on an Android device using strongSwan as the VPN server. Despite having a valid certificate and key setup on both ends, I keep getting the error "NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN" in the logs when trying to establish the VPN connection.
Details of the Issue:

VPN Server: strongSwan (on a Debian 12 VPS)

Client: Android 13 (using native VPN client)

Error Message:
Oct 13 18:22:29 m1 charon[35215]: 12[CFG] looking for an IKEv2 config for 172.28.204.140...103.82.15.193
Oct 13 18:22:29 m1 charon[35215]: 12[IKE] no IKE config found for 172.28.204.140...103.82.15.193, sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN


VPN Server Config (simplified)
conn ikev2-vpn
keyexchange=ikev2
ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024!
esp=aes128-sha1!
left=XXX  # Server's public IP address
leftcert=/etc/ipsec.d/certs/serverCert.pem
leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
right=%any  # Dynamic client IP
rightdns=8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4
rightsourceip=10.10.10.0/24
rightauth=eap-tls
rightcert=/etc/ipsec.d/certs/userCert.pem
leftauth=pubkey
leftid=XXX
auto=add

What am I missing or doing wrong?
Has anyone encountered this error or knows what might be causing the issue? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

left=XXX  # Server's public IP address  if XXX  is not 172.28.204.140 this will not work. Either remove that setting, or configure the actual IP address.

@ecdsa actually XXX is just i put here.. in actual config i put my public IP.. same with leftId. Is it probably limitation of ECS Alibaba?

Again, if that's not the IP that the packets will have as destination when they reach the IKE daemon, your config won't match. Don't configure an IP that is not local to your system (as identity that can work, but not for left).
